Grid System - Variable Card Height
I have been trying to make the card's height flexible according to the image but all my efforts have been in vain.
https://i.imgur.com/6SQBGtp.png
enter image description here
Above is the actual image of the problem
Below is the desired result (I made it using inspect for now)
https://i.imgur.com/cbLFzJX.png
enter image description here
<main className="mt-64 md:mt-32 text-center flex justify-center items-center flex-col container mx-auto">
        <div className="grid gap-6 mt-12 md:grid-cols-3">
          <Card className="p-4">
            <Image src={Image1} alt="Image-1" className="rounded-xl"></Image>
            <CardContent className="space-y-4 py-4">
              <div>
                <p className="font-bold text-lg text-gray-700">
                  Isolated House
                </p>
                <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                  Describe your vision, and let our AI do the rest.
                </p>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
          <Card className="p-4">
          <Image src={Image2} alt="Image-2" className="rounded-xl"></Image>
          <CardContent className="space-y-4 py-4">
              <div>
                <p className="font-bold text-lg text-gray-700">
                  Macro Iris
                </p>
                <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                  Describe your vision, and let our AI do the rest.
                </p>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
          <Card className="p-4">
          <Image src={Image3} alt="Image-3" className="rounded-xl"></Image>
          <CardContent className="space-y-4 py-4">
              <div>
                <p className="font-bold text-lg text-gray-700">
                  Psychedilic Girl
                </p>
                <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                  Describe your vision, and let our AI do the rest.
                </p>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </div>

      </main>

Shadcn Card
import * as React from "react"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

const Card = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "rounded-3xl bg-card text-card-foreground shadow-lg ",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
))
Card.displayName = "Card"

const CardHeader = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("flex flex-col space-y-1.5 p-6", className)}
    {...props}
  />
))
CardHeader.displayName = "CardHeader"

const CardTitle = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <h3
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "text-2xl font-semibold leading-none tracking-tight",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
))
CardTitle.displayName = "CardTitle"

const CardDescription = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <p
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("text-sm text-muted-foreground", className)}
    {...props}
  />
))
CardDescription.displayName = "CardDescription"

const CardContent = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} className={cn("p-6 pt-0", className)} {...props} />
))
CardContent.displayName = "CardContent"

const CardFooter = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("flex items-center p-6 pt-0", className)}
    {...props}
  />
))
CardFooter.displayName = "CardFooter"

export { Card, CardHeader, CardFooter, CardTitle, CardDescription, CardContent }


Elements on the same row in a grid layout are all the same height. What you are trying to achieve should be a waterfall (masonry) layout. While this can be achieved with pure CSS tricks, it's better to use the JavaScript approach for flexibility reasons.
